# How do I force a user to type only two digits after the decimal point?

Tags: c#, windows-ce

How do I force a user to type only two digits after the decimal point?

For example:

100 - good
100.1 - good
10.21 - good
10.123 - bad
21.1234 - bad

I need it at entry time - in C# and Windows CE.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a WinForms TextBox, you can trap the `KeyPressed` event and test validity/squelch input then. However this *won't* directly prevent a user from pasting in an invalid value, so you will still need to do proper validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a maskedtextbox and let .NET do the work for you. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx)
But I don't know if this is available on the WindowsCE platform.
If not: use the KeyPressed event of a normal textbox and check the input, if the input is bad. Put the key to handled so it will be not entered in the textbox.

Comment: The link you provided states it only suites the full framework.

Comment: @Shaihi: thanks I just see it in the MSDN page. @ctack: Therefore I provided an alternative in my answer.